# Network Configuration in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking

I have a ubuntu 20.04 server and found that NetworkManager is not working not working but the network is configured in the server

```
106752: br-211e1345f33f: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:5a:c3:d0:b1 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.96.1/20 brd 192.168.111.255 scope global br-211e1345f33f<br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000<br>
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00<br>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo<br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host <br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000<br>
    link/ether 96:00:01:70:fb:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff<br>
    inet 116.202.X.X/32 scope global dynamic eth0<br>
       valid_lft 85905sec preferred_lft 85905sec<br>
    inet6 2a01:4f8:c012:b833::1/64 scope global <br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
    inet6 fe80::9400:1ff:fe70:fba9/64 scope link <br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
3: br-6cdd9fdc33d3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default <br>
    link/ether 02:42:60:47:91:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff<br>
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-6cdd9fdc33d3<br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
    inet6 fe80::42:60ff:fe47:9115/64 scope link <br>
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default <br>
    link/ether 02:42:ff:8f:45:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff<br>
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
    inet6 fe80::42:ffff:fe8f:45dd/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever<br>
```

After it I have checked the `vi /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` and found:

```
network:<br>
    version: 2<br>
    ethernets:<br>
        eth0:<br>
            addresses:<br>
            - 2a01:4f8:c012:b833::1/64<br>
            dhcp4: true<br>
            gateway6: fe80::1<br>
            match:<br>
                macaddress: 96:00:01:70:fb:a9<br>
            nameservers:<br>
                addresses:<br>
                - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:2<br>
                - 2a01:4ff:ff00::add:1<br>
            set-name: eth0
```

Here I cannot find `eth0`, where is my `eth0` is configured?

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** Your question as written seems unclear, as I'm not sure what the issue is. You indicate that you're running NetworkManager, but I suspect that you're running Netplan (from the `yaml` file you show). Do you want to configure for NetworkManager or Netplan? Thanks

Comment: Actually in my server there is by default network configured but when i run the command 'ip addr' it gives the output
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 96:00:01:70:fb:a9 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 116.202.X.X/32 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 85905sec preferred_lft 85905sec
    inet6 2a01:4f8:c012:b833::1/64 scope global 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::9400:1ff:fe70:fba9/64 scope link
I tired to check the confg but its not available in Netplan